# SAP Sybase IQ - create service with complex type input parameters

Tags: sap-iq

I guys, I've a really big problem using Sybase IQ to publish a web service.
From our customer we received an XSD containing the structure of wonted input parameters for a web service that we have to built inside it.

I've never used this product but after reading this article,
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01776.1601/doc/html/san1357755072261.html, I realize that there is no way to create a procedure that can receive an input parameters formatted as complex type (for example an array of elements containing, each one, his data (attributes and text)).

Before start using "xmlcode LONG VARCHAR" (as described here: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01776.1601/doc/html/san1357755072261.html) as input in my procedure, I want to ask you, is this the real and correct solution to the problem or does it exist another way to solve this situation and produce a web service that can receive the correct input data type?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do.
After talking with SAP specialist we discover that complex types, right now, in Sybase IQ, are not supported as standard input parameters.

LONG LIFE FOR LONG VARCHAR.

No words.